# Ideal of polynomials in $k[X_1,...X_n]$ vanishing at a point $p$ is $(X_1 - p_1, ...,X_n - p_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm having a little trouble following Eisenbud here:

[image: Statement]

My problem is that I don't see how the isomorphism
$${k[x_1,...,x_n] \over \mathfrak{m}_p} \cong k$$

is constructed. This seems a bit hand-wavey to me. Any clarification would be gladly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Try to consider the "evaluation at $p$" map $f\mapsto f(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ from $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ to $k$.

Comment: @atricolf Its kernel is $I(p)$, but we want to show that this is equal to $\mathfrak{m}_p$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modding out by $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is the same as modding out by the congruence $\equiv$ generated by all of the relations $x_i - a_i \equiv 0$ which, in turn, is the same as modding out by the congruence generated by all of the relations $x_i \equiv a_i$.

And since it is a congruence and $f$ is a polynomial function:

$$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \equiv f(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \qquad \qquad (*)$$

---

To spell some things out in excruciating detail....

To save typing, let

- $A = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$
- $I = \mathfrak{m}_P$
- $R = A / I$
- $a = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$

From the general properties of polynomial rings, we know there is an "evaluation at a" homomorphism

$$ \phi : A \to k : f \mapsto f(a) $$

There is also the projection map

$$ \pi : A \to R : f \mapsto \overline{f} $$

sending a polynomial to its equivalence class modulo $I$. Because $\phi(x_i - a_i) = 0$,

$$ \bar{\phi} : R \to k : \overline{f} \mapsto f(a) $$

is well-defined, and $\phi = \bar{\phi} \circ \pi$. It is surjective because for any $c \in k$: $\bar{\phi}(\bar{c}) = c$.

The most direct method to see $\bar{\phi}$ is injective is

$$ \bar{\phi}(\bar{f}) = \bar{\phi}(\bar{g}) 
\implies f(a) = g(a) \implies f \equiv g \bmod I \implies \overline{f} = \overline{g} $$

But IMO it's more obvious to observe there is a set function

$$\bar{\rho} : |k| \to |R| : c \mapsto \bar{c}$$

which is the inverse of $\bar{\phi}$ as functions of sets, and therefore $\bar{\phi}$ must be a bijection.

A related, more general idea is that of choosing canonical preimages of the map $\phi$; that is a set function $\rho : |k| \to |A|$ with the property that $\phi \circ \rho$ is the identity function. Such a set function is called a "splitting". In this case I choose

$$\rho : k \to A : c \mapsto c $$

which turns out to actually be a ring homomorphism and not merely a set function. (*) shows that every element of $A$ is congruent, modulo $I$, to an element in the image of $\rho$, and this in turn implies that $\overline{\rho} = \pi \circ \rho$ has the property I used above.

---

A similar argument that works in this case is to look at the sequence of three homomorphisms

$$ k \xrightarrow{\rho} A \xrightarrow{\pi} R \xrightarrow{\bar{\phi}} k $$

The composite function $k \to k$ is the identity and thus invertible, therefore the composite $k \to R$ must be injective. However, by (*) we know $k \to R$ is surjective and thus bijective, and is directly seen to be an inverse of $\bar{\phi}$.

A "cheat" that streamlines this particular argument is:

- $R$ is not the trivial ring (because there is a homomorphism $R \to k$)
- $k \to R$ is surjective by (*)
- Any homomorphism from a field to a nontrivial ring is injective

and thus $k \to R$ is bijective.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see how this implies any isomorphism with $k$.

Comment: What *exactly* is the disconnect?

Comment: An isomorphism is a bijection which preserves the ring (or k-algebra) structure. How does knowing that the generators $x_i$ are sent to $a_i$ mod $\mathfrak{m}_p$ help provide such an isomorphism at all?

Comment: Because it makes it obvious what element of $k$ the isomorphism should assign to an arbitrary element of $k[\vec{x}]/\mathfrak{m}_p$.

Comment: Okay, so we send an arbitrary $f + \mathfrak{m}_p$ to $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, and then we're back to the original problem of showing that the kernel $I(p)$ of this morphism is precisely $\mathfrak{m}_p$.

Comment: You just show *directly* that that mapping is injective, surjective, and well-defined.

Comment: Thank you very much for the "excruciating detail", it is much appreciated :-)

Comment: When you write

"The most direct method to see $\bar{\phi}$ is injective is

$$ \bar{\phi}(\bar{f}) = \bar{\phi}(\bar{g}) 
\implies f(a) = g(a) \implies f \equiv g \bmod I \implies \overline{f} = \overline{g} $$"

Isn't the "$f(a) = g(a) \implies f \equiv g \bmod I$" implication really what we want to prove? We can't just assume that the ideal of polynomials vanishing at a is contained in $\mathfrak{m}_a$...

Comment: It's transitivity of equivalence, since $f(x) \equiv f(a) = g(a) \equiv g(x)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So what I considered the "meat" of the proof, that if $f(a) = g(a)$, then $f - g \in \mathfrak{m}_a$, is really all contained in the fact that an ideal generates a congruence (i.e. an equivalence relation which behaves well under ring operations). Since a polynomial is just a combination of those operations, it preserves the congruence and allows us to see that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) - f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is contained in our ideal immediately, without having to use polynomial division or anything of the sort.

Comment: So, would this argument be valid? Let $f \in I(p)$, then $0 = f(p) = f(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \equiv f(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \text{ mod } \mathfrak{m}_p$, so that $I(p) \subset \mathfrak{m}_p$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the valuation homomorphism:

$$\phi:k[x_1,...,x_n]\to k\;\;,\;\;\;\phi(f):=f(a_1,...,a_n)$$

The above is a surjective ring homomorphism, and its kernel is precisely $\,\mathfrak  m_p\,$ . Now just apply the first isomorphism theorem...

Comment: It's what I thought at first, but isn't the kernel precisely $I(p)$ and not $\mathfrak{m}_p$?

Comment: I mean, eventually we know that $I(p) = \mathfrak{m}_p$, but that's what we want to prove.

Comment: What is $I(p)$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's the ideal of polynomials vanishing at p.

Comment: Ah, okay. But you realize any polynomial $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ can be written in the form $q(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)$ for some polynomial $q$, and thus that $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is just the constant term of $q$, so it is zero only when $f\in\mathcal m_p$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't see how any f can be written in that form. We can take $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ to be a constant, or $x_1$, or $x_1^2$ (assuming p isn't the point $(0,\ldots,0))$

Comment: Cosntants are of that form -  indeed, $q=f$ in that case. In the case of $f(x_1,\dot,x_n)=x_1 = (x_1-a_1) + a_1$, so $q(y_1,\dots,y_n)=y_1+a_1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, I misunderstood what you wrote. I thought $q(x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n)$ meant some polynomial $q$ times an element of the ideal $(x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n)$. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Hah, I would have written $q\mathcal m_p$ for that. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7726/discussion-between-silencer-and-thomas-andrews)