# Is ring isomorphic to complex field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-4x+5)$ iso to $\mathbb{C}$?

I think yes. But what function may be a homomorphism?

Comment: I believe you want $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^{2}-4x+5)$

Comment: @MattJ Please do edit accordingly your post taking into account TheNumrember23's comment. It's important.

Answer (score 1):

By quotienting out $\langle x^2-4x+5\rangle$ you're specifying that $x^2-4x+5=0$ in the quotient ring. If the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, then $x$ must map something that solves that equation. You know how to solve a quadratic equation, I hope?

Comment: But answers are $2+i,2-i$ which are not real numbers

Comment: @MatJ: So what? You're looking for a isomorphism which maps your ring into $\mathbb C$, so mapping $x$ to a complex number is not a problem.

Comment: So $\varphi(f)=(f(2+i),f(2-i))$?

Comment: @MatJ: I'm not sure how to read that. You need a function whose value is a complex number, not a pair.

Answer (score 1):

Henning's answer already gave you all to solve the question, but you can try a slightly different approach: define

$$\phi:\Bbb R[x]\to\Bbb C\;\;,\;\;\;\phi(f(x)):=f(2+i)$$

This is nothing else but a valuation homomorphism. Show it is onto, and also that

$$\ker \phi=\langle\,x^2-4x+5\,\rangle$$

Now just apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Your remark that this is "slightly different" than Henning's approach might confuse the OP, since it seems, instead, to be a *continuation* of it (unless you see some different way to continue it). Also you mean **e**valuation hom.

Comment: To me this is the right approach.  In general, if one wants to show a ring isomorphism $R/I \cong S$, one's first thought (appropriately) should be to use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: The same error (valuation vs. evaluation) is in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/318145/242) of DonAntonio, so that should be fixed too. A valuation hom is a different beast.  Curiously these are the only two places on MSE that the term "valuation homomorphism" appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in need of the explicit isomorphism, you should just say this:

Given that $x^2-4x+5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb R$, the quotient is a two dimensional extension field of $\Bbb R$. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, there is only one such field: $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Timbuc Hah! Yes. I owe you a drink. I said "not of arithmetic,  but algebra" and promptly typed "calculus." Maybe my working memory is a queue.